# Adding a list of specific node on a custom JavaFX FXML control

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls, fxml

I'm trying to create a toolbar in JavaFX to add buttons using FXML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?


<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.supridatta.javafx.*?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" fx:controller="com.supridatta.javafx.MainController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@main.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <top>
        <com.supridatta.javafx.ButtonBar fx:id="buttonBar">
            <buttons>
                <ButtonBarButton path="/com/supridatta/javafx/icons/plus.png"/>
                <ButtonBarButton path="/com/supridatta/javafx/icons/minus.png"/>
                <ButtonBarButton path="/com/supridatta/javafx/icons/last.png"/>
            </buttons>
        </com.supridatta.javafx.ButtonBar>
    </top>
    <bottom>
        <Button text="Exibir todos" onAction="#showAllButtons"/>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Here is the corresponding java class:

```
package com.supridatta.javafx;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class ButtonBar extends StackPane {

    private final HBox contentPane = new HBox();
    private final ObservableList<ButtonBarButton> buttons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ButtonBar() {
        initButtonBar();
    }

    private void initButtonBar() {
        getChildren().add(contentPane);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Node> c) {
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        for (Node node : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                            contentPane.getChildren().add(node);
                        }
                    }
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        for (Node node : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                            contentPane.getChildren().remove(node);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setButtons(ObservableList<ButtonBarButton> contents) {
        this.buttons.setAll(contents);
    }

    public ObservableList<ButtonBarButton> getButtons() {
        return buttons;
    }

    public void addButton(ButtonBarButton button) {
        buttons.add(button);
    }

    public void removeButton(ButtonBarButton button) {
        buttons.remove(button);
    }

}
```

When I run the project I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce ButtonBarButton@2fd0ac8f[styleClass=button ButtonBarButton]'' to

interface javafx.collections.ObservableList.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a `setButtons` method defined, the `FXMLLoader` is going to attempt to pass in the value defined by the elements inside `<buttons>...</buttons>` to that method. (See [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements), and note in particular "A read-only list property is a Bean property whose getter returns an instance of `java.util.List` *and has no corresponding setter method*." - my emphasis.)

If you have a `getButtons()` method returning a list, and no `setButtons` method, then the `FXMLLoader` will do what you want, and pass the value corresponding to each element to the `add` method invoked on the result of calling `getButtons()`. I.e. it does

```
getButtons().add(new ButtonBarButton(...));
getButtons().add(new ButtonBarButton(...));
...
```

You either want it to do this, or you want it to do

```
   setButtons(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ButtonBarButton(...), new ButtonBarButton(...), ...));
```

So you have two fixes: either remove the `setButtons(...)` method from `ButtonBar`, or arrange to pass in an `ObservableList`:

```
        <buttons>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <ButtonBarButton path="/com/supridatta/javafx/icons/plus.png"/>
                <ButtonBarButton path="/com/supridatta/javafx/icons/minus.png"/>
                <ButtonBarButton path="/com/supridatta/javafx/icons/last.png"/>
            </FXCollections>
        </buttons>
```

Comment: Omitting the setter gave me `com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "cards" does not exist or is read-only.`, using `FXCollections` worked but is a tad more verbose.

Comment: I'm guessing things have changed since this post as I also had to add a `cardsProperty` in my case.

Comment: Nothing has changed. If you omit the setter and the `<FXCollections>` element it should work, as long as there is a `get` method returning a list. If it doesn't you have something else wrong.

Comment: @timdiels, I'm getting the error "Invalid property" when removing the setter. How did you solved that?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo I can't remember, but turns out I don't have a `cardsProperty` in FXML but I do have one in [this class](https://gitlab.psb.ugent.be/deep_genome/coexpnetviz_cytoscape_app/blob/0cdea707aec218b7f24f26962225650b5e141c8b/CoExpNetViz/src/main/java/be/ugent/psb/util/javafx/view/CardPane.java). Maybe the secret lies in that class.